# Reference field of object using string value scala macro

Tags: scala, macros

I'm trying to write a macro that will expand a given instance of a case class to a string representation. E.g. `case class Foo(a: Int); Foo(1)` would become `a -> 1`.

So I have written a typeclass to give me the field names from a shapeless `LabelledGeneric` called `FieldList`. I pass the LabelledGeneric and FieldList instances to my macro, and I can easily make the macro produce a list of all fields. However I'm not sure how I can use the string that represents the field to access the field from the object in my macro body. Here's the macro code:

```
import FieldList._
import shapeless.{HList, LabelledGeneric}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Foo {

  def foo_impl[T, L <: HList](c: blackbox.Context)
                                 (t: c.Expr[T])
                                 (gen: c.Expr[LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, L]],
                                  fl: c.Expr[FieldList[L]]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._
    reify {
      val sb = new StringBuilder
      val obj = t.splice
      val generic = gen.splice
      val fieldList = fl.splice
      // T.fieldList returns a List[String] of the class' fields. 
      obj.fieldList(generic, fieldList).foldLeft(sb) { case (builder, next) =>
        builder.append(next)
        builder.append(" -> ")
        builder.append() // How to get the value of obj.$next?
      }.toString()
    }
  }

  def foo[T, L <: HList](t: T)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, L], fl: FieldList[L]): String = macro foo_impl[T, L]

}
```

The line where i'm not sure what to do is the 3rd line of my fold with the comment.

I'm sure what i'm trying to do is possible with plain shapeless, but i'm trying to learn macros. I've looked into quasiquotes, which look like they can support this behaviour but it looks like i must choose between reify and quasiquotes and AFAICT I can only access the values of an `Expr` within a reify block (so quasiquotes wouldn't work?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splicing is perfectly possible with quasiquotes. Only you splice a `Tree`, not an `Expr` (you can go from an `Expr` to a `Tree` with `expr.tree`). Here is a solution with minimal changes to your code:

```
import FieldList._
import shapeless.{HList, LabelledGeneric}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Foo {

  def foo_impl[T, L <: HList](c: blackbox.Context)
                                 (t: c.Tree)
                                 (gen: c.Tree,
                                  fl: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val q"$_(..$args)" = t
    q"""
      val sb = new _root_.scala.StringBuilder
      val obj = $t
      val generic = $gen
      val fieldList = $fl
      val argsList = _root_.scala.List(..$args)
      // T.fieldList returns a List[String] of the class' fields. 
      obj.fieldList(generic, fieldList)
         .zip(argsList)
         .foldLeft(sb) { case (builder, (next, value)) =>
        builder.append(next)
        builder.append(" -> ")
        builder.append(value)
      }.toString()
    """
  }

  def foo[T, L <: HList](t: T)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, L], fl: FieldList[L]): String = macro foo_impl[T, L]

}
```

Do note that I have not compiled or tested this, since I don't have the rest of your code on which this depends. And if this does work, it will probably not work for more complex cases like `foo(Foo(b = "bar", a = 1))`. But it might give you a general idea on how to work with quasiquotes.

Comment: @rahilb By the way, this worked for me when I used a dummy `FieldList` of my own.

Comment: Thanks Jasper: I'm going to accept your answer, but I realised I was actually asking the wrong question for what I was trying to do! For my purpose I will need to extract the shapeless type tags from the input Tree, as I would like to know at compile time the field names (I'm still struggling with this, but that's a different story :) ). Thanks again.

Comment: @rahilb I guess you're probably best doing this either entirely in shapeless or entirely with macros.